# How to get a value of an input (text) field without document.getElementById('..')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, parameters

I have an webapplication, written in React. I have a mapped(!) component, which represents an array of states. This is the mapped child component:

```
<div className="summarized_content_div">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Benutzername: <input id='inputBenutzername' type="text" defaultValue={this.props.benutzername}/></li>
                        <li>Vorname: <input id='input_vorname' type="text" defaultValue={this.props.vorname}/></li>
                        <li>Nachname: <input id='input_nachname' type="text" defaultValue={this.props.nachname}/></li>
                        <li>E-Mail: <input id='input_email' type="text" defaultValue={this.props.email}/></li>
                        <li>Letzter Login: <input id='input_letzter_login' type="text" defaultValue={this.props.letzter_login}/></li>
                        <li>Status: <input id='input_status' type="text" defaultValue={this.props.status}/></li>
                        <input id="speichern" className="button" type="button" value="Speichern"/><input id="löschen" className="button" type="button" value="Löschen"/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Now I want the value of the input fields (input_benutzername, input_vorname,...) to be passed to the parent component on a button click. I could to something like:

```
const value = document.getElementById('whatever').value
```

and then do something with that value.

...but as i said, those components are mapped, so it always passes the value of the first mapped component, because it searches for the first element with this id (i guess).

So my final question is, how do I get the value of the input fields without using getElementById, because this is not working.

Thanks for you help

EDIT:

This is the parent component:

```
doSomethingWithTheValues = (values) => {
...
}


...
<Route path="/verwaltung/benutzer">
                            <div>
                                {this.props.benutzer.map((benutzer, index) => {
                                    return <BenutzerItem
                                        index={index}
                                        key={benutzer.id}
                                        id={benutzer.id}
                                        benutzername={benutzer.benutzername}
                                        vorname={benutzer.vorname}
                                        nachname={benutzer.nachname}
                                        email={benutzer.email}
                                        letzter_login={benutzer.letzter_login}
                                        status={benutzer.status}
                                    />
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </Route>
```

Comment: Do you mean in your app/component you have multiple elements with same **ID**?

Comment: Yes exactly, probably I should change that too :)

Comment: is this is in React.js

Comment: You should fix that first. An ID is intended to be use exactly once :)

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. IDs supposed to unique in DOM, in your case you should use class instead and on button click find the respective element using DOM traversing. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new). That might help others to debug and provide some more insight into this

Comment: @MShahzaibShoaib yes this is in React.js

Comment: @Martijn those ids are just there because i tried this as a solution, to get the values... this was not my question.

Comment: input fields in React are handle using component states not by getElementById...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input field is coded in this way in React.js:

```
 class Componentname extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {value: ''};

 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 handleChange(event) {
 this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 }

 handleSubmit(event) {
 alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
 event.preventDefault();
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     <label>
      Name:
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} 
     />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  );
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, is by also passing a function to handle the update:

```
<ExampleForm 
    data={this.state.valuesForExampleForm}
    update={(key,newValue) => this.setState({key, newValue})}
    />
```

And then in your form you have:

```
const data = this.props.data;
// other code
<li>Benutzername: <input defaultValue={data.benutzername} onChange={(e)=>this.props.update('benutzername', e.target.value)}/></li>
```

<sub>Small disclaimer: It's been a bit since I Reacted, it might be a little off.</sub>

Comment: @LeetProgramming if you want to use react then you should save input states in component ... `useState` for functional components, read react docs "handle events"